# Sending multipart/form-data with PUT request doesn't work in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, http

I am trying to send an HTTP PUT request with `"Content-Type": "multipart/form-data"` to a  Laravel application. When I change the method to POST it works.

```
$a = $request->all(); // With PUT this is empty but with POST it works fine.
```

The client-side executes the following code:

```
axios({
    method: "post", // when I try method:"PUT" and change the content type 
    url: "/api/offer",
    data: fd,
    headers: {"Content-Type": "multipart/form-data"} // here change to "x-www-form-urlencoded" it the $a array on backend is empty! 
}).then(response => {
    console.log("/offer/" + response.data)
    if (response.data)
        window.location.replace("/offer/" + this.offer.id);
    else {
        console.log("show a message that something went wrong! ")
    }
}).catch(function (error) {
})
```

I could not find anywhere in the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods/PUT) that PUT can't send "multipart/form-data"

So, can PUT send "multipart/form-data" or only POST can do that in general or it is only a PHP / Laravel Issue?

**Edit:**
Also, what difference does it make to use PUT instead of POST other than to comply with HTTP protocol and CRUD operation properly?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Laravel (HTML Forms) do not work great with Put requests so you'll need to spoof a POST request as if it was a PUT or PATCH request. On Axios you use the .post verb but within your form data you append

```
_method: "put"
```

Information from the official documentation:
https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/routing#form-method-spoofing

---

*Excerpt from the documentation:*

> HTML forms do not support `PUT`, `PATCH`, or `DELETE` actions. So, when defining `PUT`, `PATCH`, or `DELETE` routes that are called from an HTML form, you will need to add a hidden `_method` field to the form. The value sent with the `_method` field will be used as the HTTP request method

Comment: Man this saved my life after 2 days of searching, thank you so much, I think that laravel documentation is great but there are so important stuffs that are written like they are not important.

Answer (score 2):

I ran into this issue a few weeks ago myself with a Symfony 5.3 project. It only worked with POST Requests, not with PUT. [Here's an issue from the Symfony GitHub that explains it in more detail.](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/9226)

To my understanding the issues lies within the PHP implementation of those requests. The HTTP standard "PUT" supports it, but PHP does not. Here's also a link to the bug from the [PHP bugtracker](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=55815).